# Error with setpayload in mule?

Tags: mule

i fetch data from SAP and set the payload.

while setting the payload getting below error.

```
13:30:52.705     10/03/2017     Worker-0     [apl-sfa-batch-interface-v44].sfdc-sap-bw-interfaceFlow.stage1.57     ERROR

********************************************************************************
Message               : Execution of the expression "dw('payload.ZCS_SR.tables.ET_DATA.*row')" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).
Payload               : <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
                        <ZCS_SR>
                        <export>
                        <EV_FAILURE></EV_FAILURE>
                        <EV_SUCCESS>The SR Details is successfully returned from BW system</EV_SUCCESS>
                        </export>
                        <tables>
                        <ET_DATA>
                        <row id="0">
                        <CRM_OHGUID>123</CRM_OHGUID>
                        <RECORDMODE>N</RECORDMODE>
                        <CRM_OBJ_ID>123</CRM_OBJ_ID>
```

Comment: Can you show more details about your flow? How are you setting the payload?

Answer (score 1):

So it could fail for many reasons.

First guess is suspicious

```
dw('payload.ZCS_SR.tables.ET_DATA.*row')
```

It means that you pass the string "payload.ZCS_SR.tables.ET_DATA.*row" to unknown function dw().
So, actual transformation is not involved.

Usually it looks like

```
{
   arrayOfRows: payload.ZCS_SR.tables.ET_DATA.*row
}
```

Second guess would be that XML is not ended. There is no end tag even for **row** itself.

Guesses could continue endlessly.
You had provided too limited information.
It is impossible to answer based on information you had provided.